# Dealing with glade files in DVCs

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar, glade

I have three branches (let's use git for argument's sake): master, feature A, and feature B.  I have a glade file in master. The glade file is updated in both feature A and B.  Now, both are merging into develop: there's a merge problem...

Most of the time, the glade file is re-written and thus the diff is meaningless leading to having to open all the three glade files and copy-and-paste between them.

**Does anyone have a more elegant solution for glade file merges?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer) has been around way before the current DVCS.
The first release dates from 1998. even Glade 3 has been released in 2006 (Git/Mercurial were around only for one year at that time).

> This cannot be a problem only I suffer from

There might not be enough Glade project on a DVCS repo to hightlight that issue.
Even the [Glade user mailing list doesn't mention "merge" that often](https://www.google.com/search?q=merge%20site%3alists.ximian.com/pipermail/glade-users).

The main workaround is to split the xml file in as many files as possible, and include those in the program source file (with many `builder.add_from_file("mygladeFile.xml")`).
If your `glade.xml` files are small enough the risk of merge conflits is kept very low.

---

Merging 2 XML files would [require a custom merge driver](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Making-GIT-XML-aware-td3560686.html), but it [isn't a trivial problem](http://useless-factor.blogspot.fr/2008/01/matching-diffing-and-merging-xml.html), even [with xslt](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#merge) (like in [this page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/merge.html)).
Maybe an external mergetool like [**DiffDog**](http://www.altova.com/diffdog.html) (not free though) can help.

Comment: Well, since you're the only that bothered answering... Thank you for you time. Those were the solutions we came up within the team as well.  I was just hoping for more...

Comment: @Sardathrion I agree, this should be easier than it currently is.

Comment: Yes, very much so... Ah well.  Still, I am grateful for your time and advice. Merci beaucoup!